# Link preview not showing when posting to Facebook page via Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

When posting a link to Facebook page the link preview image does not show up.

I checked whether I have the correct OG tags and they're there. After posting, If I edit the post manually and add a space after the link, the preview loads as expected.

Is there a specific way to post the message and link as string so the preview loads up?

The below is a snippet of how the message is posted:

```
var postMessage = string.Format($"{content.Url} ");

var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   {"access_token", apiKeys.PageAccessToken},
   {"message", postMessage}
};

var result = httpClient.PostAsync($"https://graph.facebook.com/{pageId}/feed", new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData)).Result;
```

Thanks

Comment: I have tried adding empty strings and System.Environment.NewLine at the end to 'mimic' adding a space manually when editing the post but it still does not trigger the link preview

Comment: Try specifying the URL as `link` instead of `message`.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! You can post it as an answer so I can mark it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution given in a comment by *04FS* has fixed the issue.

All I had to do was replace `message` with `link` as shown below:

```
var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"access_token", apiKeys.PageAccessToken},
    {"link", postMessage}
};
```

This way the Graph API picks it up and link preview shows immediately after posting.